# How to avoid NULLs in String representation of Binary Search Tree?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

As a programming exercise I need to rewrite some existing methods and classes that make up a binary tree. (The method signatures and constructors have to stay the same). Somehow I don't really seem to understand what I have done here.

Does the *toString* method have to public because it overwrites the *Object* class's *toString* method? And how can I avoid the nulls from being returned?

Here is the code I have come to so far:

**Tree Class**

```
Node root = null;

void addNode(int val) {
        Node newNode = new Node(val);
        root = newNode.addNode(root, val);
    }
```

**Node Class**

```
Node(int val) {
    val = val;
    left = null;
    right = null;
}

Node addNode(Node focusNode, int newNodeVal) {

    if (focusNode == null)
        return this;
    if (newNodeVal == focusNode.val)
        return focusNode;
    if (newNodeVal < focusNode.val)
        focusNode.left = this.addNode(focusNode.left, newNodeVal);
    else
        focusNode.right = this.addNode(focusNode.right, newNodeVal);

    return focusNode;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.left + " " + this.val + " " + this.right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` to store the `String` representation of the node and append the data of the children nodes only in the specific node is not `null`. Here's an example using [infix navigation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29) on the nodes:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (this.left != null) {
        sb.append(this.left);
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    sb.append(this.val);
    if (this.right != null) {
        sb.append(' ');
        sb.append(this.right);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: If `this.left` is appended. It will automatically call the `toString` method. And therefore it recursivly appends the values of the nodes? Is this right?

Comment: @TomTomTom yes, you're right. This implementation is recursive.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String toString() {
    if(this.left==null){
        return this.val + this.right;
    } else if (this.right==null){
        return this.left + this.val;
    } else if (this.left == null && this.right == null){
        return "";
    } else {
        return this.left + " " + this.val + " " + this.right;
    }
}
```

You assign your nodes to null to start, and your toString method assumes that they have been altered. Imagine a tree where you added 5, then 3. Then called toString on the tree. It will try to print the node, 5 is the value, left is 3, right is null. When you try to call

```
return this.left + " " + this.val + " " + this.right;
```

You are saying to print

```
3 5 NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize `left` and `right` with an empty `Node` object (with no `val`) and when you print it you will see `null` as the `val` of an empty `Node`:

```
Node(Integer val) {
    this.val = val;
    left = new Node(null);
    right = new Node(null);
}
```

This only works if you make `val` an `Integer`.

There is also a bug in your code:
`val = val` will leave `this.val` untouched. You have to use `this.val = val;`

`toString()` is **overridden** not **overwritten**. It has to return a `String` and you can't really avoid `null`s if your `Node` is a leaf.

What you can do is writing `toString()` in a way it can be meaningful to have a `null` as `val` like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return "#{val = " + val + ", left = " + left + ", right = " + right + "}"
}
```

Please note that this will traverse your tree recursively so to print your tree you only have to call `root.toString()`.